# Why doesn't assign() values to a list element work in R?

Tags: r, list, assign

I'm trying to use assign values in an object in a list.  What I want to do is change some elements.  For example:

```
x <- list()
x$test <- 1
assign("x$test", 2)
x$test == 1
     [1] TRUE
```

Any thoughts?  I need to use assign because I am building a function which will take the names of the objects within the list (x) as inputs.

Comment: Note there's a big difference between `x$test` and `x[['test']]`. See the doc on [`extract(..., drop=TRUE)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you're out of luck. From the help file:

> ‘assign’ does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to
>   set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.
>
> Note that assignment to an attached list or data frame changes the
>   attached copy and not the original object: see ‘attach’ and ‘with’.

If you're passing `names(x)` as input, couldn't you use:

```
nms <- names(x)
for ( n in nms )
    x[[n]] <- 'new_value'
```

Also, are you intending for your function to modify some global variable? e.g.:

```
x <- list(test=1)

f <- function(...)
   x$test <- 2

f() # want x$test = 2 ??
```

Because this won't work (scope problems). You can make it work with a bit of footwork (`<<-`), but this is generally considered bad practice as it's easy to intrtoduce unintentional bugs into your code.

If you could give an example of why you want this function/what purpose it will serve, we could help you find an alternative solution.

Comment: Great, thanks so much -- I was not aware that I could use the [[n]] syntax, which is totally sufficient.  Really appreciate the info.

Answer (score 11):

See what happens when you assign to "x$test":

```
x <- list()
x$test <- 1
assign("x$test", 2)
ls()
[1] "x"      "x$test"
```

The element "test" in "x" is still 1, and you extract it with `x$test` but `get("x$test")` will be the value 2 from that name.

Why not just use the names directly? I.e.

```
this.name <- "test"
x[[this.name]] <- 2
```

Comment: I don't know why the other answer has been accepted, but as mdsumner says, why not using the name directly? that works absolutely flawless.

Comment: assign() allows you to specify the environment in which the assignment happens, which can be very helpful. This is in contrast to <<- which only assigns to the global environment. So, x[[name]] is not as general a solution as assign(x$name, value, envir = my_env) would be.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is:

```
x <- list()
x$test <- 1
assign("x$test", 2)
x$test == 1
TRUE
eval(parse(text="x$test<-2"))
x$test == 1
FALSE
```

The `eval(parse(text=""))` command can be very useful in this context.

Sincerely

Comment: To paraphrase Thomas Lumley : "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question."  Avoid constructs like this at all times if there's a more sensible solution. Here that solution is `[[`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried <<- ?  I used this to assign names and values to a list from within a function in a post yesterday (see ["Combine a series of data frames and create new columns for data in each"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551555/combine-a-series-of-data-frames-and-create-new-columns-for-data-in-each)).